# Android app memory integrity

Tags: android, memory, operating-system

When an app gets put in the background and the app takes up too much memory. Is it possible for the operating system to corrupt the memory so that when the app is launched again unexpected behavior might ensue? Or will it completely kill the app when it needs the memory so that when I relaunch I'm in a clean state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.
For more detail on how Android manages memory and how it affects applications, services, etc, see http://mobworld.wordpress.com/2010/07/05/memory-management-in-android/ and http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/04/multitasking-android-way.html